# What's the difference between the `tree -L 1 /` with `tree -L 1`?

Tags: linux, tree

In Linux I use the `tree` command to show the directory construction.

If I use `tree -L 1 /` in root directory:

```
[root@localhost /]# tree -L 1 /
/
├── a.out
├── bin -> usr/bin
├── boot
├── dev
├── etc
├── home
├── lib -> usr/lib
├── lib64 -> usr/lib64
├── media
├── mnt
├── opt
├── proc
├── root
├── run
├── sbin -> usr/sbin
├── srv
├── sys
├── tmp
├── usr
└── var
```

But if I use `tree -L 1`:

```
[root@localhost /]# tree -L 1

.
├── a.out
├── bin -> usr/bin
├── boot
├── dev
├── etc
├── home
├── lib -> usr/lib
├── lib64 -> usr/lib64
├── media
├── mnt
├── opt
├── proc
├── root
├── run
├── sbin -> usr/sbin
├── srv
├── sys
├── tmp
├── usr
└── var
```

You can see there is `.` and `/` difference, I don't know if there is more deep meaning, can't be only the `.` and `/` looks like, alright?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`tree -L 1 /` will always display a directory tree rooted at '/'.   It is as if you executed the following commands: `cd /; tree -L 1; cd -`

`tree -L 1` displays displays a directory tree rooted in your current directory - which may or may not be '/'.